# VIM Regex replacing words

Tags: vim, regex

Which regex do I have to use in VIM to replace all words 'to' from a text with the word 'foo'?
(I don't want to replace 'to' when it happens in a word like 'together').

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this should work:

```
:%s/\<to\>/foo/g
```

Using `\<` and `\>` ensure that "to" will only be replaced if it is an entire word. `\<` matches the start of a word and `\>` the end. This way it won't turn your "tod" into "food" :)

Comment: Much nicer than my solution for sure :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's a simpler way, but:

```
:%s/\(\w\)to\(\w\)/\1foo\2/gc
```

would do the trick

EDIT:
John T has posted the simpler way :D